# in jDownloads 3.9, how do I make the link to downloads the actual download name, rather than "?task=download.send"

Tags: joomla-3.x

I recently updated jDownloads on my Joomla website from 3.2 to 3.9. I noticed that now, when I hover over a link in a category, instead of using the download's name, like it used to, it's now using a function with "?task=download.send" and the ID number. How can I revert to the old functionality, so that links look nicer?

I tried looking all over the new options for something similar to 3.2's "search engine friendly" option, but can't see anything like that. Do I need to update the layout, maybe? I don't know what to change, or what to look for.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, maybe a silly question, but does the download start when you click on the link?

Comment: yes, everything works, but my links just look like a jumble of numbers instead of being informative.